# Difference between DWORD and DWORD32

Tags: c++, types, dword

According to [Windows Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), both DWORD and DWORD32 are "A 32-bit unsigned integer" except IntSafe.h and the other is defined in BaseTsd.h. What's the difference or maybe advantage in using one over the other?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a windows DWORD is *always* a 32-bit unsigned integer. DWORD matches the windows API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows APIs are full of decades of C `#define` and `typedef` debris.

What you are looking at is some of that debris.  Maybe at some point they thought about having a `DWORD` that scaled in size, while `DWORD32` would not.

But that hope is long dead.  They are almost certainly identical types, and almost certainly will never become non-identical.

If you where using something called `DWORD16` and `DWORD64` for whatever reason, the name `DWORD32` would fit in, or if you for some other reason really want to stress the number of bits in your `DWORD32` type, that type might be a better idea.  Otherwise, pick one, use it, and ignore the other.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical. `DWORD` is maintained for backwards compatibility with decades of legacy code, and is always 32-bit. `DWORD32` is the same data type and merely explicitly indicates that it is 32-bit. `DWORD32` was introduced at the same time as `DWORD64` and `DWORD_PTR` were introduced, when the API was being updated to support 64-bit development.